# Separate and add numbers from an external file with .sh

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, ifs

Question #1

How can I read a column and add each entry from a file using .sh?

Example file:

```
10000:max:100:1,2:3,4
10001:jill:50:7,8:3,2
10002:fred:300:5,6:7,8
```

How to use `IFS=':'` to read that file with a .sh file line by line and add the third part so that it would output the addition e.g. 450

```
$ ./myProgram myFile.txt
450
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple awk one-liner command would do this job.

```
$ awk -F: '{sum+=$3}END{print sum}' file
450
```

For each line, awk would add the column 3 value to the variable `sum`. Printing the variable `sum` at the end will give you the total count. `-F:` sets the Field Separator value to colon.

Comment: `#! /usr/bin/env bash

file="$1"
externalprogram "$FILE" <other-parameters>

$ awk -F: '{sum+=$3}END{print sum}' $1` Would that then be the way to add the file I want as an argument to call in terminal @SMA

Comment: Sorry @Avinash Raj. I posted my second part of my question as part of the question rather than a comment

Comment: you don't need to put `$` before `awk` in your script just `awk -F: '{sum+=$3}END{print sum}' file` would be fine.

Comment: Thanks @avinash Raj I took that out. It still doesn't output correctly. Thank you again though

Comment: Why you added this `externalprogram "$FILE" <other-parameters>` ?

Comment: I removed that file. It was stated in lots two of the tutorials I looked at. It works now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Try using awk like:

```
awk -F':' '{sum+=$3} END {print sum}' myfile.txt
```

Here -F is delimeter where we say fields are delimeted with colon ":" present in file myfile.txt
We add $3 value to sum. And once that's done, we print the value of sum.